# what's the point of life?

Tags: questions

Lets think that we have no proof that an after life exists, then why would go through ups and downs of life just to for everything to suddenly go black? isn't it just easier to die? if you die you don't have to face any challenges and surely you won't be rewarded. But why would you care? Death is inevitable.

FYI I am not depressed nor mentally ill, just curious to know others opinions as no one I know could really answer my question.

Comment: Let's say that afterlife does exist, what difference does it make? Endless ups and downs can be as pointless as those limited in time, and vice versa, duration is irrelevant. If you die you won't have any joys, surprises or discoveries either, it is just empty. You choose to see it one way or the other here and now, inevitable death is also irrelevant. It is amusing how people always look for a "point" where they are not, in the future, but if it is there it shall never come, even with life eternal. Make every present moment have a point instead, or the "after" won't help.

Comment: I don't know how this question and the other can be duplicates.  One invites answers from a position of philosophical insight.  (that's this one noting "we have no proof of an afterlife" inclusion).... but the other question linked includes "If God is there, where did God come from? What is our purpose from him? If he is not, what are we?" which invites answers of an entirely different nature altogether.  Assuming God need mentioning in a discussion on the philosophy of life, should be by choice only, and not have other questions pushed into it.  IMHO.

Comment: Noting the tags on the linked question = "existentialism, existence of God" and a couple of others.  This question has only the tag "Questions".   I think if the other question stands, this too should stand, and stand apart.

Answer (score 1):

1. Objectively the only point of life is to pass your DNA further. To procreate.
2. And on a personal level the point of life is something you need to find for yourself. It's your own quest to find a meaning for your life (or just live and have fun) and not a fixed written formula that someone gonna give you.